# facebook shares' friends amount with fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm still able to retrieve amount of the friends, who 'likes' post, created with my app (POST: /feed call, only message is set).

```
$request = [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'call' => '/fql',
        'params' => [
            'q' => sprintf("SELECT friend_count 
                            FROM user
                            WHERE uid IN ( SELECT user_id
                                           FROM like
                                           WHERE post_id = '%s' ) 
                                      AND uid <> '%s'",
                    $postId,
                    $myUserId
                ),
        ]
    ];
$fbRequest = new FacebookRequest($this->getSession(),
                                 $request['method'],
                                 $request['call'],
                                 $request['params'], 
                                 'v2.0');
```

Is there any possibility to do the same things with people, who has shared this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via FQL IMHO, but via the Graph API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/sharedposts/

But you'll need the `read_stream` permission, which is nearly impossible to get approved for an app.